# Weird : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Execution failed for task app:dexDebug

Tags: android

I didn't implement new libs but this problem occured while coding :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output F:\Android_Donbas\ReDonbasIDEANew\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=F:\Android_Donbas\ReDonbasIDEANew\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

my build.gradle :

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-jdbc-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
}



packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.t'
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have hit the 65k methods limit. To use Google Play Services with more granularity, follow [this guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html), you can use only the parts that you want. This will possibly fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in 65k limit

Comment: The official documentation for this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 4):

You can fix the limit issue by enabling multdex in your build.gradle by adding "multiDexEnabled true". For more information see http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

Referred from [Why did this happen? How do i fix this? Android: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344481/why-did-this-happen-how-do-i-fix-this-android-unexpected-top-level-exception).

Answer (score 2):

Adding multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig in build.gradle solved my problem

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with adding these in build gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true


    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

another solution can be removing unnecessary libraries