# Why did this happen? How do i fix this? Android: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Tags: android, android-support-library

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /home/prem/Development/Android-sdk/sdk/build-tools/21.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/prem/currencysave/Android/CurrencySave/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/home/prem/currencysave/Android/CurrencySave/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Comment: This is your _error_, then what is your question?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @Arulkumar - that's not helpful - a seemingly obscure error message has a perfectly obvious implied question of "Why did this happen?  How can I fix it?"  That's not to say the question shouldn't be closed - it is perfectly clear and as ligi has demonstrated answerable, but it is also a duplicate of one that has been asked here quite a few times before.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - Thank you for your support. But I edited the question for more clarity for others.

Comment: @Arulkumar  I know this is my error, came here to find the solution. I think #stackoverflow is to discuss only :)

Comment: Your edit makes the question worse, by removing the important part of the error message, which is one that has been covered here many times before.

Answer (score 10):

You run into the method count limit. Either you use multidex or reduce the number of methods ( e.g. with proguard ) 
Please read this: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html