# stripe-android lib 1.0.3 upgrade causes execution error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, stripe-payments

I upgraded to the latest stripe-android lib: `compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3'`

which only required me to add currency to the Card constructor ("USD"):

```
Card stripeCard = new Card(
  cardNumber, month, year, cvc, name,
  line1, line2, city, state, zip, "US", "USD"
);
```

But this causes an execution error in Android Studio after a successful compile:

[image]

The execution error goes away when I downgrade to: `compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0'`

Here's a portion of my **build.gradle**:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.website.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 20
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use ./gradlew assemble --info to get more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I reached the 65k limit for the first time. My ultimate solution was to include the specific APIs of Google Play Services that I needed instead of all of them. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Running `./gradlew assemble --info` as suggested by @Gabriele Mariotti helped give me a slightly more detailed "UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL DEX EXCEPTION". With that, I came across this post: [Why did this happen? How do i fix this? Android: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344481/why-did-this-happen-how-do-i-fix-this-android-unexpected-top-level-exception), which directed me to this documentation https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

Currency can't be passed as a parameter to the constructor, but you can set it using the card's Builder or by setting the property explicitly, i.e.

```
//using the Builder
Card card = new Card.Builder("4242424242424242", 9, 2018, "123").currency("usd").build();

//or set the property once you've created the card
card.setCurrency("usd")
```

Comment: That's not true. There is a constructor in v1.0.3 that accepts currency among other things. And v1.0.0 had a constructor that took an address (which I'm using). See here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/commit/144a0b46087eb056a33f8c3f332767225ee4ca93#diff-eab66c49c35a280f9f8b4158cc452257L167 Is it a bad idea for me to use this constructor opposed to the Builder?