# Android gms:play-services:8.1.0 DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Gradle build fails with a multi-dex exception after I've changed gms:play-services:7.5.0 to 8.1.0

Error is caused by exceeding the 65k methods limit and gets fixed by changing version back or removing couple of libraries, but doesn't sound like a proper solution, cause you usually need more than couple of libraries.

What is the best solution to bypass the 65k method limit?

**EDIT**:

**Best option** is to prevent the DexIndexOverflowException issue by using separate parts of gms library like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0` or `com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Execution failed for task app:dexDebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286156/weird-unexpected-top-level-exception-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug)

Comment: Are you using the full gms:playservices library or are you using the per-feature versions as detailed here?  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I'm using full library

Comment: Well, don't use the full library :D

Comment: You should not use the full library unless you are using features in each part of the library. That is a proper solution because you should be aware of what part of the library you are using and not include the remaining ones.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like there is huge method count difference between 7.5 and 8.1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only way to fix the issue is to add

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

to enable the multi dex support, but it will work only on v21 and higher.

For versions prior than v21, you will need to set `multiDexEnabled true` and add support for multidex:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

**Thanks to @NasaGeek**:
Best option is to prevent multidex error by using per-feature versions of google play services. Full list of per-feature versions is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)