# android studio showing error in app running

Tags: android

i am trying to run my project in android device.it ran successfully on another device but it's not running in my device showing this error:

```
Error:Note: /home/ashik/Desktop/project/app/src/main/java/com/example/ashik/project/Patient_list.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

my Patient_List.java like this:

```
package com.example.ashik.project;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.core.operation.ListenComplete;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Patient_list extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Patient> patients;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_patient_list);

        patients=new ArrayList<Patient>();
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);




        Firebase firebase=new Firebase("https://cancertable.firebaseio.com/").child("cancer");
        firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String,Object> newpost=(Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                String nm= String.valueOf(newpost.get("name"));
                String age= String.valueOf(newpost.get("age"));
                String city= String.valueOf(newpost.get("city"));
                String occ= String.valueOf(newpost.get("occupation"));
                String cond=String.valueOf(newpost.get("condition"));
                Patient patient=new Patient();
                patient.setName(nm);
                patient.setAge(age);
                patient.setCity(city);
                patient.setCondition(cond);
                patient.setOccupation(occ);

                patients.add(patient);


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                setlist();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void setlist()
    {
        Arrayadapter arrayadapter=new Arrayadapter(Patient_list.this,patients);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    }
}
```

my 
build gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and build gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ashik.project"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.dakatso:livebutton:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

it ran successfully yesterday and showing exact output from firebase but now on my DEWAV MAXIMUS (MAX990)(Android 4.2.1 API 17)

Comment: I suggest [googling the error message](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=DexIndexOverflowException).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Execution failed for task app:dexDebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286156/weird-unexpected-top-level-exception-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in android in build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
 }
}
```